# Adjusting edge scroll boundaries for touchpad in 17.10

Tags: touchpad, 17.10, synaptics, wayland

Previously with X.org and all, synclient and xinput were pretty good when it came to customization. Now after 17.10 and Wayland I can't use synclient to make fine adjustments to my touch pad anymore, and my once so brilliant "scroll pad" (adjusted edge scroll boundaries to cover the entire pad) doesn't work.

Does anyone know if it is possible to fine tune settings like these in 17.10 and while using wayland? Any hints in the right direction would be highly apprecitated.

Update: this is what I do in my script today:

```sh
#!/bin/sh
synclient VertEdgeScroll=1
synclient TouchpadOff=0
synclient RightEdge=5579
synclient LeftEdge=1781
synclient PalmDetect=1
```

Comment: [The article by libinput developer](http://who-t.blogspot.ru/2017/01/the-definitive-guide-to-synclient.html) makes impression that synctool is not supported under Wayland. It does make sense, given synctool is superseded by libinput, though you can ask under the article for clarification. FTR, xinput is definitely would not work on Wayland *(except maybe for XWayland clients, dunno on this one)*.

Comment: @Hi-Angel so from what I've read there I would have to submit a bug report / feature request for this?

Comment: Your usecase of making whole touchpad surface to scroll is a pretty special. I think you might have better luck asking the question to who-t over the link I provided earlier, he usually replies within a day or so.